# How can NDSolve be used to solve the heat equation as a first order system?

Tags: differential-equations

For reasons left unsaid, I tried to approximate the solution of the heat equation with initial and boundary data as a first-order system using the following code block:

```
Clear[u, v, t, x, tend]
tend = 5;
pde = {D[u[t, x], t] == v[t, x],  D[u[t, x], x] == v[t, x]};
bc = {u[0, x] == 1.0 - x^2, v[0, x] == 0, v[t, 0.0] == 0.0, 
u[t, 1.0] == 0.0};
{usol, vsol} = 
 NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tend}, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MinPoints" -> 30}}}]
grflux = Plot[usol[t, 0], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True]
```

This produces a result by treating the PDE as a DAE, but does not give the correct answer as can be seen by running the code. 
A handmade Mathematica code, using for example MacCormak's method, can be easily written to approximate the solution of the first-order system as a DAE and produce the correct answer. Is there a better way to pose the system to Mathematica so that its DAE solver produces the correct result?

Comment: Isn't the heatequation a second order pde `D[u[t, x], t] ==D[u[t, x], {x,2}]`?

Comment: What if you use `D[u[t, x], t] == D[v[t, x], x]` for the first pde in your system?

Comment: Michael E2 has the correct answer. I read the code several times and missed the obvious omission. With this fix, the problem is totally resolved. Thanks!